# Jenkins Jira-Plugin Could not find matching constructor

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jira-plugin

I'm trying to config Jenkins Jira Plugin through groovy script but getting an error

```
    WARNING: Failed to run script file:/var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/k_JiraPluginConfig.groovy
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.plugins.jira.JiraSite(java.net.URL, java.net.URL, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, null, null, java.lang.Boolean)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1732)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1532)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at k_JiraPluginConfig.run(k_JiraPluginConfig.groovy:13)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
    at jenkins.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript.execute(GroovyHookScript.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript.execute(GroovyHookScript.java:127)
    at jenkins.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript.run(GroovyHookScript.java:110)
    at hudson.init.impl.GroovyInitScript.init(GroovyInitScript.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1065)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my groovy script looks like

```
import hudson.plugins.jira.JiraProjectProperty
import hudson.plugins.jira.JiraSite
import jenkins.model.*

def env = System.getenv()
def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
JiraProjectProperty.DescriptorImpl config = jenkins.getExtensionList(JiraProjectProperty.DescriptorImpl.class)[0]

JiraSite jiraSite = new JiraSite(new URL(env.JIRA_URL),
                            new URL(env.JIRA_URL),
                            env.JIRA_USERNAME,
                            env.JIRA_PASSWORD,
                            true,
                            true,
                            true,
                            null, null, false)
jiraSite.setDisableChangelogAnnotations(false)
jiraSite.setTimeout(10)
jiraSite.setDateTimePattern('EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z')
jiraSite.setAppendChangeTimestamp(true)
config.setSites(jiraSite)
config.save()
```

And this code I derived from the config file of Jira-plugin and that XML file looks like below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson.plugins.jira.JiraProjectProperty_-DescriptorImpl plugin="jira@2.5">
  <sites>
    <hudson.plugins.jira.JiraSite>
      <url>https://jira.mycompany.com/</url>
      <useHTTPAuth>false</useHTTPAuth>
      <userName>Jenkins</userName>
      <password>{secretPassword}</password>
      <supportsWikiStyleComment>true</supportsWikiStyleComment>
      <recordScmChanges>true</recordScmChanges>
      <disableChangelogAnnotations>false</disableChangelogAnnotations>
      <updateJiraIssueForAllStatus>true</updateJiraIssueForAllStatus>
      <timeout>10</timeout>
      <dateTimePattern></dateTimePattern>
      <appendChangeTimestamp>true</appendChangeTimestamp>
    </hudson.plugins.jira.JiraSite>
  </sites>
</hudson.plugins.jira.JiraProjectProperty_-DescriptorImpl>
```

Not sure what I'm missing here, any help would be appreciable.

**Additional details**

Jenkins version - 2.9.3

Jira version - 7.2.2

Jira-Plugin version - 2.5

Jira-Plugin repo - https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-plugin

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the [JiraSite Constructor](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/jira/JiraSite.java#L176-L177) and update JiraSite constructor call in your groovy script to match it. The constructor for JiraSite is like below

```
JiraSite(URL url, URL alternativeUrl,
         String userName, String password,
         boolean supportsWikiStyleComment, boolean recordScmChanges, 
         String userPattern, boolean updateJiraIssueForAllStatus, 
         String groupVisibility, String roleVisibility, 
         boolean useHTTPAuth)
```

So based on the constructor signature, you need to update your constructor call in groovy script like below:

```
JiraSite jiraSite = new JiraSite(new URL(env.JIRA_URL), new URL(env.JIRA_URL),
                        env.JIRA_USERNAME, env.JIRA_PASSWORD,
                        true, true,
                        null, true,
                        null, null,
                        false)
```

I have assumed userPattern is not required so gave as null, you can update it with what is required for you. That was the argument you missed in your constructor call

Hope this helps

Comment: @anoop-philip If this helps, can you accept as answer? :)

Comment: thanks, I will check it later today and accept the answer.